# What could slow Excel on one PC but not another?

Tags: configuration, microsoft-excel

I have 2 PC with the same configuration. I open an Excel File (~5M) on the network from both PC. The opening  is not the fastest but that's ok. The problem is that on one PC, Excel is really slow. I mean if I hit the left arrow 10 times, I will have finished hitting like 3 seconds before the active cell is the next 10th one.

The file contains graphics that takes time to initialize on the slowed computer.

Both PC have the same graphic cards, same driver version; both remote access to the file on a local network. Both configured to perform calculations automatically. Both Excel 2007. Both Windows 32bit.

On the other PC it runs really fast.

I really don't know what to check next.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What are the speeds like if you copy the file to the local drive before opening it? Same results?
If not, it might be a bad NIC on one PC.

Comment: Done complete spyware/virus checks and all Windows (+Office) updates?

Answer (score 1):

When I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue that's not generating error message or other clues to direct my attention, I often run Process Monitor and watch what the application is doing with the OS.  Sometimes this reveals lots of file system calls that are denied or otherwise unsuccessful.  If you have a working system and a non-working one then comparing them for any obvious differences might give you the direction you're looking for.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

I would also recommend trying to determine whether this difference is caused by the file contents (do other spreadsheets in this location have the same problem on this machine?  Sometimes spreadsheets have references to other files also -- see http://www.exceltip.com/st/Quickly_Creating_Links_between_Workbooks_in_Excel_2007/1366.html), file format (e.g. XLSX vs. XLS vs. CSV), or the application settings (a simple way to test this might be to login as another user / guest user, presumably with default preferences set, and see if the problem still occurs).

Answer (score 0):

This: http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/windows/microsoft_office_2003/microsoft-office-word-excel-outlook-slow-when-connected-to-network-but-fast-when-not/

May be relevant; though this was a write up I made w.r.t. office 2003 having issue scanning for network printers; this could be the case if your "fast pc" is the print host, whilst the "slow pc" is sharing the printer via the other pc.